# Product of a symmetric and anti-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, symmetric-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

I have the following question about matrices,
Let $S$ and $A$ be two $n \times n$ matrices which are respectively symmetric and anti-symmetric. Can I conclude anything about the products $SA$ or $AS$, are they symmetric or anti-symmetric?

This is part of a bigger problem where I have already shown,
$$ \langle x, Ax \rangle = 0$$
For $A$ antisymmetric, but I require that 
$$ \langle Mx, Ax \rangle = 0$$
For some matrix M, what conditions could I impose on $M$ to satisfy this, I was hoping symmetry would be sufficient or do I require something stronger such as diagonality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The matrix product does not preserve the symmetric nor the anti-symmetric property. A simple example of this phenomenon is the following.

Pick

$$S=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1\\
1 &2
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 &0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then $$SA=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1\\
1 &2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 &0
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2\\
2 &-1
\end{pmatrix}$$

which is symmetric nor anti-symmetric. Similarly,

$$AS=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 &0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1\\
1 &2
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -2\\
2 &1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Again, this is not symmetric nor anti-symmetric.

Comment: Although it appears each the results SA and AS are indeed each antisymmetric in the provided example...

Comment: @IntuitivePhysics an antisymmetric matrix has all zeros in the main diagonal. So $SA$ and $AS$ are both not antisymmetric nor symmetric

Comment: I think we agree that anti-symmetric  is that $M$=$-M^T$ and $M$=$M^T$.  So, while  While, Symmetric matrices can include one's with diagonal elements in that definition. But you sre right that neither SA nor AS is either of these in your post.   I must have misread negative signs in the matrices when I read your post the first time.